# Which solution for a detailed product search?

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudsearch

I need to build some kind of product search and i'm not sure, which way I should go.

Requirements:

- Proximity Search
- Custom Ranking
- Auto-correct-Suggestions, like in Google when you type "Winipedia", it suggest "Wikipedia".
- Indexing PDFs as field value of a search entity
- German Language Support for Autocorrect-Suggestions
- Auto-complete support

I tried it with AWS CloudSearch, but their support sucks if you don't pay extra for support and they don't support German yet, nor Auto-complete.

Is there any search solution with all the functions I need? Elasticsearch looks good, but I can't find any detailed feature list about it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Regards
Nils

Comment: Solr has Extracting Request Handler which indexes PDFs out of the box. I doubt ES has this functionality. Solr uses Apache Tika for this, which you can integrate yourself.

Comment: @aitchnyu ElasticSearch has the same functionality, also via Tika: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type.html

Comment: You should give a try to Algolia. It's really fast, easily customizable & it matchs perfectly the "database search" feature. You can try the demos on their website: https://www.algolia.com/demos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Solr and ElasticSearch have the features you need, choosing between them is only a matter of taste. :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply! ;) Do you have any experience with one of them? which one is easier to setup and which one offers better support, or larger community to get help?

Comment: I have more experience with Solr, which has the advantage of sharing its development tree with Lucene (same developers, same release dates,  most new Lucene features are immediately available). Although ElasticSearch probably has a smaller community, it has been written with distribution in mind from the beginning and its community is growing very very fast...

Comment: ElasticSearch also uses Lucene under the hood. Lucene is a search library; solr is one client that uses solr, ElasticSearch is another.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 actively marketed solutions in the market:
1. Swiftype
2. Easyask
3. Unbxd

All these solutions handle it pretty well and better than Lucene and Solr (Tried and tested). Go for Lucene / Slor if you have the time and money to improve it on your own... or just buy a off the shelf solution.